# Images go corrupt in my website but work in general

Tags: html, css, image, web

Ive been trying to set some images for my portfolio page but Ive been having this problem   http://prntscr.com/axg0yr  . The code I try is  `<li><img src = "images/news.svg" id = "GithubImage"/> <a href = "https://github.com/x"> GitHub </a></li>` , and after that `height:64px; width: 64px;` as they are supposed to be. What can have gone wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Is the path right?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put it in object tag, like this

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="path/image.svg">
    Your browser does not support SVG
</object>
```

For security reasons, browsers will disable SVG scripts, linking and other types of interactivity when they’re added to your page with an img tag. In addition, IE9, Chrome and Safari won’t apply stylesheet rules to the SVG if they’re defined in a separate CSS file.